# Is optimistic synchronization wait-free for adds, removes, and contains?

Tags: multithreading, optimization, synchronization, locking, optimistic-locking

If you scroll one page down from the page 205 of book "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" (Elsevier, 2012 ISBN 9780123977953), to page 206 (Section 9.6 Optimistic Synchronization):[https://books.google.com/...](https://books.google.com/books?id=vfvPrSz7R7QC&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=9.6%20optimistic%20synchronization&source=bl&ots=e_kHlOTKcJ&sig=kN6r6ogI2C4ki5rfycOCK2Z4fNo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiow9uPyYbOAhVD54MKHe9UCz8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=9.6%20optimistic%20synchronization&f=false) you'll see the add/remove/contains methods for optimistic synchronization (Figure 9.11 The `OptimisticList` class: the `add()` method traverses the list ignoring locks, aquires locks, and validates before adding the new node. Figure 9.12 The `OptimisticList` class: the `remove()` method traverses ignoring locks, acquires locks, and validates before removing the node. [page copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug2Ei.png)).

In the following section on lazy synchronization, it goes on to state (while referring to optimistic synchronization)

`The next step is to refine this algorithm so that contains() calls are wait-free, and add() and remove() methods, while still blocking, traverse the list only once`

This seems to be saying that the contains method isn't wait free, and thus neither would the add or remove methods be. But I can't seem to see why that would be the case.

Comment: Implementation of all 3 methods calls .lock(), which may wait. That is why them are non wait-free.

Answer (score 2):

**Lazy synchronization** is based on **optimistic synchronization**. On lazy synchronization you traverse the list only once, not acquiring any locks, unlike e.g. hand-over-hand locking. When you have reached your destination for remove/add/contains you need to lock the current and predecessor node.
The big difference is that when you remove a node, you first have to mark it as deleted and then physically delete it (garbage collector).

Why is contains wait-free?
Unlike optimistic synchronization, we don't need to lock the current node. Recall that we lock the current node so that another thread can't delete it while we are returning true.
Because the current node would have been marked, we can simply check, if the current node is marked and has the desired key. No need for any locks. This makes it wait-free.
A sample code could look like this:

```
public boolean contains(T item) {
 int key = item.hashCode();
 Node curr = this.head;
 while (curr.key < key) {
 curr = curr.next;
 }
 return curr.key == key && !curr.marked;
}
```